Getting access denied error while scraping API data using Python and Selenium
I am trying to automate a process where I am trying to access the API of a website product list page and scrape product related information. When I use urls1[] array data, my code is giving proper output but when I am using urls2[] array data, I am getting access denied error.
Below is first set of URLs:
urls1 = [
'https://staging1-japan.coach.com/feature/holiday2024_nkento.html',
'https://staging1-japan.coach.com/shop/new/women',
'https://staging1-japan.coach.com/shop/women',
'https://staging1-japan.coach.com/shop/men/bags',
'https://staging1-japan.coach.com/shop/collection-2',
'https://staging1-japan.coach.com/shop/gift/women/bestseller',
'https://staging1-japan.coach.com/shop/coachworld',
'https://staging1-japan.coach.com/shop/coachreloved/coach-reloved'
]

Below is the second set of URLs:
urls2 = [
'https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/shop/black-friday-deals/view-all', 
'https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/shop/women/view-all', 
'https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/shop/men/view-all', 
'https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/shop/bags/view-all', 
'https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/shop/gifts/view-all', 
'https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/shop/shop-by'
]

Below is my code:
    import requests
    import warnings
    from time import sleep
    # Suppress SSL warnings
    warnings.simplefilter('ignore', requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
    # List of URLs to iterate over
    urls = [
         'https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/shop/black-friday-deals/view-all', 
    'https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/shop/women/view-all', 
    'https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/shop/men/view-all', 
    'https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/shop/bags/view-all', 
    'https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/shop/gifts/view-all', 
    'https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/shop/shop-by'
    ]
    # Full header simulation of a real browser session
    headers = {
        "Cookie": "auth-bypass=true;",  # Ensure this is up-to-date
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Referer': 'https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/shop',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'TE': 'Trailers'
    }
    # Start a session to handle cookies across requests
    session = requests.Session()
    # Iterate over each URL in the list
    for url in urls:
        count_of_items = 1  # Reset item count for each URL
        page = 1  # Starting page for pagination
        if '/shop' not in url:
            print(f"No products available in this PLP: {url}")
            continue
        try:
            while True:
                ct = count_of_items + 15  # Adjust count to match pagination
                if page == 1:
                    full_url = f"{url}"
                else:
                    full_url = f"{url}?page={page}"
                if 'api/shop' not in full_url:                     
                    full_url = full_url.replace('/shop', '/api/shop')
                print(f"Fetching: {full_url}")  
                response = session.get(full_url, headers=headers, verify=False)
                if response.status_code == 403:
                    print(f"Access denied for URL {full_url}. Check cookies or headers.")
                    break
                print(f"Response Status Code: {response.status_code}")
                if response.status_code != 200:
                    print(f"Failed to retrieve data from {full_url}")
                    break
                products = response.json().get('pageData', {}).get('products', [])       
                if not products:
                    print(f"No products available in this PLP: {full_url}")
                    break
                pro_count = response.json()['pageData'].get('total', 0)
                print(f"Total products found: {pro_count}")
                break
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception raised for URL {url}: {e}")
            continue

Output of my code when using urls1[]:
No products available in this PLP: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/feature/holiday2024_nkento.html
Fetching: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/shop/new/women
omation/testing.py
No products available in this PLP: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/feature/holiday2024_nkento.html
Fetching: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/shop/new/women
No products available in this PLP: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/feature/holiday2024_nkento.html
Fetching: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/shop/new/women
Fetching: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/shop/new/women
Response Status Code: 200
Response Status Code: 200
Total products found: 349
Fetching: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/shop/women
Response Status Code: 200
Total products found: 349
Fetching: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/shop/women
Response Status Code: 200
Response Status Code: 200
Total products found: 991
Fetching: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/shop/men/bags
Fetching: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/shop/men/bags
Response Status Code: 200
Total products found: 138
Total products found: 138
Fetching: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/shop/collection-2
Response Status Code: 200
Total products found: 346
Fetching: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/shop/gift/women/bestseller
Response Status Code: 200
Total products found: 76
Fetching: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/shop/coachworld
Response Status Code: 200
No products available in this PLP: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/shop/coachworld
Fetching: https://staging1-japan.coach.com/api/shop/coachreloved/coach-reloved
Response Status Code: 200
Total products found: 20

Output of my code when using urls2[]:
Fetching: https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/api/shop/black-friday-deals/view-all
Access denied for URL https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/api/shop/black-friday-deals/view-all. Check cookies or headers.
Fetching: https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/api/shop/women/view-all
Access denied for URL https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/api/shop/women/view-all. Check cookies or headers.
Fetching: https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/api/shop/men/view-all
Access denied for URL https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/api/shop/men/view-all. Check cookies or headers.
Fetching: https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/api/shop/bags/view-all
Access denied for URL https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/api/shop/bags/view-all. Check cookies or headers.
Fetching: https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/api/shop/gifts/view-all
Access denied for URL https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/api/shop/gifts/view-all. Check cookies or headers.
Fetching: https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/api/shop/api/shop-by
Access denied for URL https://staging1.coachoutlet.com/api/shop/api/shop-by. Check cookies or headers.


403 means the server doesn't want to talk to you.  Often this is based on your ip address domain or your browser agent.

So, the staging1-japan.coach.com server is willing to talk to you, but the staging1.coachoutlet.com server isn't.

Yes I got that but is there any solution for this? How can I bypass it? @john-gordon

Hi @John Gordon, any update on this?

You could try using a VPN, to hide your real IP address from the site.

I saw the second set of url asking for a password and username (most likely you're dealing with a basic auth problem which seems internal assets, sadly no bypass for you)
